# Prove that a function converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x -> x_0}f(x) = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{x -> x_0}|f(x)| = 0$.

I know in order to prove to if and only if statement we need to prove if $\lim_{x -> x_0}f(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x -> x_0}|f(x)| = 0$ and if $\lim_{x -> x_0}|f(x)| = 0$, then $\lim_{x -> x_0}f(x) = 0$.

How can I prove these two statements using definition of limit?

Comment: Well what is the definition of $lim_{x->x_0} f(x) = 0$?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t \forall x: |x - x_0|$ we have $|f(x) - 0| < \epsilon $. I think I can very easily prove first statement

Comment: You are missing the $|x-x_0| < \delta$. I recommend you to draw these statement on a graph if you have never done it before. If you write the definition for the limit of |f(x)| you will get exactly the same statement proving the equivalence

Comment: You can use $||f(x)|-0|=||f(x)||=|f(x)|=|f(x)-0|$ in combination with the definition of $lim$ in order to prove both statements.

Comment: If you get intuition from the squeeze theorem, note that $-|f(x)|\le f(x)\le |f(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}|f(x)|=0$ given $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}f(x)=0$:

By definition of a limit, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

We need to show that there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$, $||f(x)|-0|<\epsilon$.

However, $||f(x)|-0|=||f(x)||=|f(x)|=|f(x)-0|$, so if we choose $\delta_1$ to be the same as $\delta$, we have proven the limit is $0$.

The reasoning for the proof of the converse is pretty much the same, you just need to turn $|f(x)-0|$ into $||f(x)|-0|$ instead of the other way around.

I hope this helps!